# Calculating Floating point Operations Per Second(FLOPS) and Integer Operations Per Second(IOPS)

Tags: benchmarking, processor, cpu-speed, flops

I am trying to learn some basic benchmarking. I have a loop in my Java program like,

```
float a=6.5f;
int b=3;    
for(long j=0; j<999999999; j++){            
       var = a*b+(a/b);
    }//end of for
```

My processor takes around 0.431635 second to process this. How would I calculate processor speed in terms of Flops(Floating point Operations Per Second) and Iops(Integer Operations Per Second)? Can you provide explanations with some steps?

Answer (score 2):

You have a single loop with 999999999 iterations: lets call this 1e9 (one billion) for simplicity. The integers will get promoted to floats in the calculations that involve both, so the loop contains 3 floating-point operations: one mult, one add, and one div, so there are 3e9. This takes 0.432s, so you're apparently getting about 6.94 GFLOP/s (3e9/0.432). Similarly, you are doing 1 integer op (`j++`) per loop iteration, so you are getting 1e9/0.432 or about 2.32 GIOP/s.

However, the calculation `a*b+(a/b)` is loop-invariant, so it would be pretty surprising if this didn't get optimized away. I don't know much about Java, but any C compiler will evaluate this at compile-time, remove the `a` and `b` variables and the loop, and (effectively) replace the whole lot with `var=21.667;`. This is a very basic optimization, so I'd be surprised if `javac` didn't do it too.

I have no idea what's going on under the hood in Java, but I'd be suspicious of getting 7 GFLOPs. Modern Intel CPUs (I'm assuming that's what you've got) are, in principle, capable of two vector arithmetic ops per clock cycle with the right instruction mix (one add and one mult per cycle), so for a 3 GHz 4-core CPU, it's even possible to get 3e9*4*8 = 96 single-precision GFLOPs under ideal conditions. The various `mul` and `add` instructions have a reciprocal throughput of 1 cycle, but the `div` takes more than ten times as long, so I'd be very suspicious of getting more than about CLK/12 FLOPs (scalar division on a single core) once division is involved: if the compiler is smart enough to vectorize and/or parallelize the code to get more than that, which it would have to do, it would surely be smart enough to optimize away the whole loop.

In summary, I suspect that the loop is being optimized away completely and the 0.432 seconds you're seeing is just overhead. You have not given any indication how you're timing the above loop, so I can't be sure. You can check this out for yourself by replacing the ~1e9 loop iterations with 1e10. If it doesn't take about 10x as long, you're not timing what you think you're timing.

There's a lot more to say about benchmarking and profiling, but I'll leave it at that.

I know this is very late, but I hope it helps someone.

Emmet.